# How to publish the points selected by the tool 'select' on rviz?

Tags: rviz, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have tried using [turbo-ros-pkg](https://github.com/tu-rbo/turbo-ros-pkg). After doing catkin_make install(which worked with no errors), an object file is created in the devel/lib folder. How do I use the plugin now to publish the selected points on a topic? Also, will the data type of these messages be sensor_msgs::PointCloud2?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298355/how-to-publish-the-points-selected-by-the-tool-%27select%27-on-rviz?/) by [surabhi96](https://answers.ros.org/users/32900/surabhi96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2018-07-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As taken from the [readme file](https://github.com/tu-rbo/turbo-ros-pkg/tree/master/selected_points_publisher) on the repository:

```
The tool can be loaded by clicking on the "Add new tool" button (plus sign) and
must be used to select points.
 
Additionally publishes selected points on /selected_points topic.
```

[RVIZ itself will create this topic and publish messages to it]

The type of these message will be `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2`

Hope you get this working okay.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [surabhi96](https://answers.ros.org/users/32900/surabhi96/) on 2018-07-24**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd Thank you so much. I wonder how I didn't get that line previously. This was trivial, my bad. Thanks again!

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-07-24**:
No worries. It's easy to miss things the first time around sometimes.

**Comment by [surabhi96](https://answers.ros.org/users/32900/surabhi96/) on 2018-07-25**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd I know this is a bit off-topic but is it possible to publish intensity values via this package? I tried changing the data type of the points to pcl::PointXYZI in the .cpp and .h file but that doesn't work. Or, is there any better way to select the desired points and use the data?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-07-26**:
This would require a significant re-working of the package. Where would these intensity values come from? They generally represent infrared albedo information for LiDAR scans.

**Comment by [surabhi96](https://answers.ros.org/users/32900/surabhi96/) on 2018-07-26**:
Ohkay. On selecting multiple points using the 'Select' tool, I can see the x, y, z values along with Intensity and ring num in the 'Selection' panel. Since the turbo-ros-pkg inherits from 'Select', I thought there would be some way of accessing and publishing the intensity values of the points.

**Comment by [dong_ym](https://answers.ros.org/users/31913/dong_ym/) on 2018-09-02**:
Hi,I want to know how to use this package. I want to select a region of PointCloud2 in rviz, and record such data in file, how it works? Thank you very much.

**Comment by [surabhi96](https://answers.ros.org/users/32900/surabhi96/) on 2018-09-03**:
@dong_ym It is very easy! Once you clone the package into your system, you will have to load the functionality that this package provides in rviz. For adding this new tool, just click the '+' button on the top right hand side of rviz. You can then write a subscriber to access the x,y,z coordinates

**Comment by [dong_ym](https://answers.ros.org/users/31913/dong_ym/) on 2018-09-03**:
ok， I will have a try. But I have a question that the selected region can't hold in screen, I want to know instructions of this functionality.By the way,the selected region publish topic is  /selected_points?

**Comment by [surabhi96](https://answers.ros.org/users/32900/surabhi96/) on 2018-09-03**:
what do you mean can't hold? Once you drag and release the points from your cursor, you will see the coordinates of the selected points being published in the terminal from where you launched rviz. Yes, it is /selected_points. Read the documentation